# Returning a promise and catching an error

Tags: javascript, promise, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

I'm a bit confused about when an error in a promise is passed to the catch handler.

With the following bit of code, if `promise2` causes an error, is that passed to the catch at the bottom? Also, does my return inside the first "then" return `promise2` as a promise, or does it return `doc`.

```
promise1(foo).then(doc =>{
  return promise2(doc).then(doc => {
    return doc
  })
}).then(doc =>{
  console.log(doc)
}).catch(err => {
  console.error(err)
})
```

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `then` can return a promise, but if something fails you need to explicitly return a reject. In the example below changedDoc is passed to the second `then` as newDoc

```
promise1(foo).then(doc =>{
  // changedDoc = doc.....
  if (good things happened) {
     return changedDoc;
  } else {
     return new Promise.reject("error");
  }
}).then(newdoc =>{
  console.log(newdoc)
}).catch(err => {
  console.error(err)
})
```

Comment: Yes ... but the point of Promises it to use their Monadic structure to avoid needing to `throw`

Answer (score 0):

`then` can receive two parameters:

- one for the case when the promise is fulfilled
- other for the case when the promise is rejected (purposefully, or because an exception was thrown)

If there is an error in the execution of the code, either in the fullfilled, or the rejected, the execution will continue in the next rejected callback. In your code the first rejected callback, is the one specified in the `catch` callback. If that block didn't exist, the exception would keep bubbling up to the first `catch` block in the code. And, if there was no such block, it would be handled by the browser, and shown as an error to the user.

If you [look at the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), you'll see that `catch` is just like a `then` that receives only the second parameter:

```
Promise.prototype.then(onFulfilled, onRejected)

Promise.prototype.catch(onRejected)
```

You can also have a look at [this documentation on handling exceptions with promises](http://www.2ality.com/2014/10/es6-promises-api.html#catching_exceptions).

The whole idea of promises is being able to chain then, so that the succes is propagated to the `onFullfilled` callback, which can run without error, and return something for the next `onFullfilled` handler, or run with error, with will be handled by the next `onRejected`. The error can be a purposefull rejection, or an unhandled exception.